# Does Hash.slice support strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Does Hash.slice support strings ?

so for example

```
a = {"b" => 1, "c" => 2}
a.slice("b")
```

If not then how does it react to strings ?

I am trying to track down a bug where data is being lost and I think it is because the keys in hashes switch intermittently between strings and symbols. Filtering is done exclusively using `Hash.slice(*keys)`

Comment: is `a` actually HashWithIndifferentAccess ? There have been bugs in the past where some operations on a HashWithIndifferentAccess would return a plain Hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, `Hash#slice` with a single key value (such as a string) from the hash returns a hash containing the matching key-value pair, or `nil` if it isn't matched to a key. `Hash#slice` takes any number of arguments, each representing a key. See the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice), and note `*keys` argument.